# Add custom field in the view of yii2 which is not in model

Tags: php, yii2

I am getting a problem while saving a form in yii2.

I have created a custom field with name like other fields `Myposts['categoryLevel2']`. This field is not in model. It is a conditional field. When I post my from I assign its value to a model attribute Like:

```
$categoryLevel3 = $request->post('categoryLevel3');
if(!empty($categoryLevel3)){
    $model->category=$categoryLevel3;
}
```

Now because categoryLevel3 is not there in table post so it is giving error.
**Getting unknown property: frontend\models\Posts**
I know the issue. The error is because in `$_POST` array there is a field `categoryLevel3` now and it is not in table so `$model->save()` is throwing exception. I tried `unset($_POST['categoryLevel3'))` but that also did not work. Can anyone help me on this?

How can I create a filed in view which is not in table and ignore it before `$model->save`?

Comment: I think this approach is better (which solved my problem):
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46143764/yii2-how-to-send-new-variable-from-view-to-controller/46143999#46143999](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46143764/yii2-how-to-send-new-variable-from-view-to-controller/46143999#46143999)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add Public property `'categoryLevel3` in Your Post Model Class.

```
 class Post extends yii\db\ActiveRecord{
   public $categoryLevel3;

   public function rules(){

       return [

          [''categoryLevel3' , 'required']
   ...
           ];

     }
   }
```

Comment: thanks Double H. I have just started with yii2 and I was not even thinking about this. You saved my time. It is now working perfectly