# Yii2: How to send new variable from view to controller?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have a table called **persons** with **id** and **name** fields.

I have a **create.php** view that loads the model called **Persons** and now I want to add a checkbox called **hasCar** to show if a person has a car (so it is a boolean condition).

Then I have the **send** button that send the **$model** array of the **form** to the controller so I need to add the **hasCar** variable to **$model** array.

But the checkbox is not a column of the **persons** table so I got some errors because it is not part of the model.

I added the checkbox in this way but it is not working, of course.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'hasCar')->checkbox(); ?>
```

Is it possible to send the **hasCar** variable inside the **$model** array? I mean, how can I send the **hasCar** variable to the controller when the **send** button is pressed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add custom field in the view of yii2 which is not in model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33970348/add-custom-field-in-the-view-of-yii2-which-is-not-in-model)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass the variable to the $model object orbit is affiliated with a db table, you are right about this. You need to pass the variable to the controller via a request method (GET, POST).

Try :

```
Yii::$app->request->post()
```

for POST, and :

```
Yii::$app->request->get()
```

for GET.

Also on the form add the checkbox as an HTML class component.

EXAMPLE:

CONTROLLER:

```
...
$hasCar = Yii::$app->request->post('hasCar');
....
```

VIEW:

```
...
// We use ActiveFormJS here
$this->registerJs(
    $('#my-form').on('beforeSubmit', function (e) {
        if (typeof $('#hasCar-checkbox').prop('value') !== 'undefined') {
            return false; // false to cancel submit
        }
    return true; // true to continue submit
});
$this::POS_READY,
'form-before-submit-handler'
);
...
<?= HTML::checkbox('hasCar', false, ['id' => 'hasCar-checkbox', 'class' => 'form-control']) ?>
...
```

More on ActiveFormJS:
[enter link description here](https://yii2-cookbook.readthedocs.io/forms-activeform-js/)

I hope this answer covered you.

Damian

Comment: The hasCar variable should be required. How can I validate it? I can do it in the model file but I would like to not use the model.

Comment: You cannot use the backend validation. Yii2 has a known bug regarding this issue and it is not yet solved. You can use frontend validation. At least that is how i do it. You first attach a handler to the activeform submit event. I will update my answer with an example.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new model extending Person that contains hasCar member, and load the model from PersonForm class, such as:

```
class PersonForm extends Person
{
    public $hasCar;

    public function rules()
    {
        return array_merge(parent::rules(), [
            [['hasCar'], 'safe'],
        ]);
    }   

    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array_merge(parent::attributeLabels(), [
            'hasCar' => 'Has car',
        ]);
    }      
}
```